# Сортировка строк двумерного массива по возрастанию

Tags: java, массивы, сортировка

Дан массив а(10,10), заполненный случайными значениями в диапазоне от 50 до 100. Создать программу, сортирующую указанный массив по строкам по возрастанию.
Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так:

```java
public class Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][] = new int[10][10];
        int min = 50;
        int max = 100;
        int b;
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = min + (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        for (int i = 1; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 1; j < a.length; j++) {
                if (a[i][j] < a[i][j - 1]) {
                    b = a[i][j];
                    a[i][j] = a[i][j + 1];
                    a[i][j + 1] = b;
                    System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Сравниваете первый элемент со вторым, а обмениваете местами с третьим... гламурненько.

Comment: Вопрос неясен. Что значит "сортировать по строкам по возрастанию"? Для каждой строки рассортировать ее элементы независимо от других строк? Или рассортировать массив верхнего уровня, сравнивая между собой его элементы (строки)? Если второе, то как определены отношения порядка на строках? Но в любом случае, то, что вы написали -- это не сортировка. Почитайте где-нибудь про алгоритмы сортировки, информации очень много.

Comment: Расскажите сначала что с этим кодом не так. Что он выводит, что он должен выводить? Еще рекомендую вместо случайных чисел забить маленький массив прямо в коде. Так будет легче тестировать и продемонстрировать ошибку. Вообще почитайте [Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```java
public class Class {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int a[][] = new int[10][10];
        int min = 50;
        int max = 100;
        int b;

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                a[i][j] = min + (int) (Math.random() * (max - min + 1));
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("...........");

        // начинать надо с 0. почему у вас с 1 ?
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                // надо с чем-то сравнивать! а то вы использовал
                // обычные $i и $j, а переменную-индекс для сравнения
                // не ввели и пытаетесь +-1 делать
                for (int k = j + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
                    // у вас неправильный знак неравенства
                    if (a[i][j] > a[i][k]) {
                        b = a[i][j];
                        a[i][j] = a[i][k];
                        a[i][k] = b;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        // и хорошо бы вывод что получилось видеть 
        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j++) {
                System.out.print(a[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
        System.out.println("...........");
    }
}
```

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Строки двумерного массива `int[][]` - это одномерные массивы `int[]`. Для сортировки в данном случаем можно использовать метод [`Arrays.sort(int[])`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#sort(int%5B%5D)). Ваш код может выглядеть так:

```java
int[][] arr = new int[10][10];

// заполняем массив случайными числами от 50 до 100
IntStream.range(0, 100).forEach(i ->
        arr[i / 10][i % 10] = (int) (50 + Math.random() * 51));
```

```java
// выводим получившийся массив
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [67, 51, 73, 64, 92, 88, 59, 100, 74, 51]
// [100, 76, 76, 67, 54, 54, 62, 78, 72, 66]
// [63, 88, 92, 66, 78, 82, 55, 68, 60, 54]
// [84, 72, 95, 75, 57, 68, 77, 81, 52, 65]
// [98, 65, 67, 94, 93, 96, 94, 60, 99, 82]
// [87, 85, 60, 91, 58, 92, 66, 64, 50, 53]
// [76, 86, 60, 66, 91, 60, 85, 60, 90, 72]
// [81, 78, 50, 76, 92, 71, 80, 70, 98, 94]
// [57, 62, 87, 58, 88, 98, 72, 95, 82, 93]
// [94, 76, 50, 70, 74, 91, 71, 97, 56, 72]
```

```java
// сортируем строки двумерного массива,
// т. е. вложенные одномерные массивы
Arrays.stream(arr).forEach(Arrays::sort);
```

```java
// выводим отсортированный массив
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
// [51, 51, 59, 64, 67, 73, 74, 88, 92, 100]
// [54, 54, 62, 66, 67, 72, 76, 76, 78, 100]
// [54, 55, 60, 63, 66, 68, 78, 82, 88, 92]
// [52, 57, 65, 68, 72, 75, 77, 81, 84, 95]
// [60, 65, 67, 82, 93, 94, 94, 96, 98, 99]
// [50, 53, 58, 60, 64, 66, 85, 87, 91, 92]
// [60, 60, 60, 66, 72, 76, 85, 86, 90, 91]
// [50, 70, 71, 76, 78, 80, 81, 92, 94, 98]
// [57, 58, 62, 72, 82, 87, 88, 93, 95, 98]
// [50, 56, 70, 71, 72, 74, 76, 91, 94, 97]
```