# Как вывести многомерный массив в консоль?

Tags: java, массивы

Создал многомерный массив (3x5), теперь надо вывести в консоль. Как можно это сделать?

```java
public class Map {
    private String[][] cells = {
            {" ", "[]", " "},
            {"[]", "[]", "[]"},
            {"[]", "[]", "[]"},
            {"[]", "[]", "[]"},
            {" ", "[]", " "}};

    //Getters and Setters
    public String[][] getCells() {
        return cells;
    }

    void see() {
        System.out.println(getCells());
    }
}
```

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Map map = new Map();

        map.see();
    }
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5061912/printing-out-a-2-d-array-in-matrix-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можете попробовать использовать - [Arrays.deepToString](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#deepToString(java.lang.Object[]))

```
void see() {
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(cells));
}
```

Вывод:

```
[[ , [],  ], [[], [], []], [[], [], []], [[], [], []], [ , [],  ]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно вывести двумерный массив построчно:

```java
String[][] cells = {
        {"  ", "[]", "  "},
        {"[]", "[]", "[]"},
        {"[]", "[]", "[]"},
        {"[]", "[]", "[]"},
        {"  ", "[]", "  "}};

Arrays.stream(cells).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

Вывод:

```
// [  , [],   ]
// [[], [], []]
// [[], [], []]
// [[], [], []]
// [  , [],   ]
```

---

См. дополнительно:

- [Сортировка строк двумерного массива по возрастанию](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214433/419583)
- [Вывод двумерного массива](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1214494/419583)