# Вывод двумерного массива. Java

Tags: java, массивы, консоль, вывод

Создал новый метод, прописал там следующее:

```java
static void changeDiagonal() {
    System.out.println("Задание №4");
    int[][] listDoubleDiagonal = new int[10][10];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < listDoubleDiagonal.length; i++) {
        listDoubleDiagonal[i][i] = 1;
        listDoubleDiagonal[i][listDoubleDiagonal.length - 1 - i] = 1;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(listDoubleDiagonal));
    System.out.println();
}
```

На данный момент в консоль выходит массив, но каждый его элемент не начинается с новой строки, а хотелось бы. Подскажите, пожалуйста, какой-то может есть способ другой для вывода в 10 строк?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Элемент двумерного массива - это одномерный массив. Обходим двумерный массив и выводим его элементы. Это можно сделать в цикле:

```java
for (int i = 0; i < listDoubleDiagonal.length; i++) {
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(listDoubleDiagonal[i]));
}
```

Можно на стримах:

```java
Arrays.stream(listDoubleDiagonal)
        .forEach(arr -> System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr)));
```

Answer (score 1):

Вывод двумерного массива построчно:

```java
int[][] arr = new int[10][10];

// заполнение массива
IntStream.range(0, 10).forEach(i -> {
    arr[i][i] = 1;
    arr[i][9 - i] = 1;
});

// вывод построчно
Arrays.stream(arr).map(Arrays::toString).forEach(System.out::println);
```

```
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0]
[0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0]
[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0]
[1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1]
```